# Interview : concatenate and addition how compiler knows

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is the question I got;

> When we are concatenating 2 string using "+" symbol and adding 2
>   integers using "+" symbol, How the compiler identifies that the
>   operation is concatenation OR Sum of integers?

Comment: From both operand types? From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx); _Binary `+` operators are predefined for numeric and string types. For numeric types, `+` computes the sum of its two operands. When one or both operands are of type `string`, `+` concatenates the string representations of the operands._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler knows the two operands of the `+` operator. It uses that to determine the operator action to use.

For `string` it calls the `Concat` method. If the first operand is a `string` and the other an `int` for example, it calls this overload: [`String.Concat(object, object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khca9w90(v=vs.110).aspx). That code does a `.ToString()` on the integer, which yields it textual representation.

On numerics, there is some logic to determine which of the `+` operators to use (so `long` if you add an `int` to a `long`). This behavior is all predefined in the CLR.

Read more on the [`+` operator on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx).